# Buffon's experiment with squares

Tags: probability, geometry, trigonometry, monte-carlo, geometric-probability

Say, we'd like to make the [Buffon's experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle) but with squares instead of needles.

Notation:

- $d$ is the distance between lines
- $b$ is the square side length
- $y$ is the distance from the center of the square to the nearest line
- $\alpha$ is the acute angle between one of the diagonals and the vertical line

My attempt to illustrate it:

[image: Buffon's experiment with squares]

Now we note that $y$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,\frac{d}{2}]$  and $\alpha$ in $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$. Furthermore, the square crosses the closest line if $$y\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}b \cos\ \alpha$$

Now if $E$ is the the event when the square crosses a line then: $$P(E)=\frac{\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}b \cos\alpha \ \text{d}\alpha}{\frac{d}{2}\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{4b}{\pi d}$$

Therefore $$\pi= \frac{4b}{P(E)d}$$

Does this make sense?

Unfortunately, my textbook gives a different answer: $$\pi= \frac{4b(\sqrt{2}-1)}{P(E)d}$$

Any clarifications or alternative solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Following your analysis, I get $\pi = \frac{4b}{P(E)d}$.

Comment: @SammyBlack: thank you for catching the mistake, I fixed it. But it's still different from the textbook's answer.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm not sure.  I looked at what happens when the square is big enough for it's diagonal to span the gap between lines $(b \sqrt{2} > d)$.  In that case, the integral breaks into two pieces at $\alpha = \arccos \frac{d}{b\sqrt{2}}$ and the answer looks more complicated, but in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to know something about the relative sizes of $b$ and $d$. The discrepancy between your answer and the book's answer may have something to do with this.

If $b \leq \frac{d}{\sqrt{2}}$, the boundary of the square intersects the line in either $0$ or $2$ places with probability $1$, and $P(E)$ is the probability that it intersects in $2$ places. The [Buffon's noodle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_noodle) argument tells us that a curve of length $L$ expects to intersect lines at distance $d$ in $\frac{2L}{\pi d}$ places. As the perimeter of the square is of length $4b$, the expected number of intersections is $\frac{8b}{\pi d}$; since those intersections always come in pairs, the probability of intersection is $\frac{4b}{\pi d}$ as you've calculated.

On the other hand, if $b > \frac{d}{\sqrt{2}}$, the boundary of the square could intersect the lines in $0$, $2$, $4$, or maybe even more places. So knowing the expected number of intersections is no longer good enough to tell us anything about the probability (though it does give a bound: certainly the probability of intersection is still at most $\frac{4b}{\pi d}$).