# Buffon's experiment with squares instead of lines.

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

How one can compute the probability in Buffon's experiment if there are squares instead of lines?

I can find only answers to the problem, but no substantial explanation. For example, [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Buffon-LaplaceNeedleProblem.html).

And [here](http://whistleralley.com/buffon/buffon.htm) it states that the problem is easy to solve for a calculus student. And I am one, but still I can not do that.

[Here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27969276?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) I found an explanation. Even though I hope for an easier one, it seems like it is not that difficult to get it.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693730/buffons-experiment-with-squares